# How to schedule a rake tasks in Google Cloud?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, google-cloud-platform

I had a Rails application on Heroku, and to schedule some rake tasks I used an add-on called Scheduler. I had to change my application to Google Cloud and I do not know how to schedule the same rakes. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml

This will allow you to setup cron scripts that call out to a web endpoint.  My suggestion would be to add an API endpoint that can trigger the code you need ran.  If security is an issue, you can always add http basic auth behind the endpoint and pass it along in the URL payload from the cron.

If you wanted to get dirty with it, you could trigger the rake code from the controller itself, though I wouldn't recommend this approach as it's bad design, but instead just move all the code your executing in rake to the controller.

If the above approach doesn't fit your needs, then the next best option would be to setup a sidekiq instance and use that to schedule and run code from your codebase.